# Two Windows in Electron / React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, electron, windowstate

**What I Want**

Initially, mainWindow is visible and callWindow is closed.

If I type in searchInput and click on button in mainWindow, then I want:

- `callWindow.show()`
- callWindow runs `this.props.dispatch(push("/calls", {searchInput}))`

**Where I'm Stuck**

in main.js...

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(options)
callWindow = new BrowserWindow(options)
ipcMain.on("buttonClick", (event, arg) => {
    callWindow.show();
    // STUCK! How to make callWindow react code run: this.props.dispatch(push("/calls", {searchInput}))
});
```

In react code..

```
onButtonClick() {
    ipcRender.send("buttonClick", input)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ipcMain.on("buttonClick", (event, arg) => {
    callWindow.show();
    callWindow.webContents.send('dispatch', searchInput);
    // STUCK! How to make callWindow react code run: dispatch(push("/calls", {searchInput}))
});
```

At callWindow renderer (callWindodw React code)

```
componentDidMount() {
   ...
   ipcRenderer.on('dispatch', (event, searchInput) => {
      this.props.dispatch(push("/calls", {searchInput}))
   })
}
```

Comment: Full code here. I'm sure you are using classBased component. So you should add this listener to your lifecycle function.

Comment: i love your name by the way